# Extjs - show PDF from byte array in javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-9, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

First of all, two things:

- I know, there a lot of similar questions, but none of them helped me finding a solution for my problem
- I'm a beginner - in every single aspect of programming...

**Problem:**
Receiving a byte array from a webservice, I need to show a PDF in Internet Explorer 9.
Following code is working in Chrome, but in IE9, all I receive is a dark gray panel, where the
PDF is ment to be.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.DocumentFrame', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
alias: 'widget.documentframe',
layout: 'hbox',
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;
    var binaryData = me.value.DocumentData;
    var source = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + (binaryData);

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
                {
                xtype: 'box',
                itemId: 'panel-document-frame',
                width: 600,
                height: 600,
                autoEl: {
                    tag: 'object',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    type: 'application/pdf',
                    data: source
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    me.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

- Is there a problem with the MIME-Type?
- Do I have to encode or decode the byte array?
- Am I doing wrong on trying to use *Data URI* for PDF on IE9?

I just don't understand why this works in other browsers, but not in IE9, especially while giving a path to a stored PDF-File is working without any problems (even in IE9).
I do this by setting the data-parameter for autoEl like this:

```
data: 'content/files/Designer.pdf'
```

Note: by doing this in IE9, a MessageBox appears: "An Active X Control on this Page Might be Unsafe to Interact with Other Parts of this Page". At the very moment, i do not care about this.

*Am I so wrong on trying to show a PDF from a byte array?* I'm really stuck on this and any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

**-edit-**

binaryData may be a wrong or irritating name for  the variable. As far as I know, this is a byte array, looking like:

> JVBERi0xLjQNCiXi48/TDQolDQold1BERjMgYnkgV1BDdWJlZCBHbWJIIFYzLjY1WzQwMjY1MzIxNl0gMzJiaXQgIHVuaWMgDQolDQolDQoxIDAgb2JqDTw8L1R5cGUvTWV0YWRhdGEvU3VidHlwZS9YTUwvTGVuZ3RoIDE0OTIgPj4NCnN0cmVhbQo8P3hwYWNrZXQgYmVnaW49Iu
>
> ...
>   ...
>   ...
>
> GQ5N2VlYjczYmVkZjczZWM5Pl0NCi9JbmZvIDIgMCBSDQo+Pg0Kc3RhcnR4cmVmDQo1NTgyDQolJUVPRg0K

After all, this is the complete value of the variable `source`:

http://pastie.org/private/upqwjrkfwgmz1hxrx9vha

**-edit2-**

- We are using Adobe Reader Version 11.0.3 (11.0.03.37).
- De-/Activating the AdobePDF-Plugin in IE9 has no effects - problem remains the same

Comment: Have a look at the Data URI limitations in IE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: thats somehow what I asked ("Am I doing wrong on trying to use Data URI for PDF on IE9?"), but it looks like, as if there is no possibility to do this in IE9. Should I try to download the file instead? Is this possible?

Comment: If the pdf data is coming from the server you can download it. In one of my apps I had to send client generated data to server and then download it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Colombo and me mentioned before, the data uri limitations in IE do not allow to use PDF.
I think, our approach is similar to the solution, Colombo described in his second comment.

After searching high and low, reading lots of sources and trying whatever I could imagine, the only solution to solve my problem was putting the whole logic into an ASP.NET Controller (credits to my co-worker):

This code is working, but in a "dummy-state"!

**The byte array is located in "archiveDocument.Document.DocumentData"**

```
public class PdfController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult View(Guid id)
    {
        if (id == Guid.Empty || id == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("id null or emtpy", "id");

        using (var serviceClient = ServiceClient.GetAuthClient<ArchiveDocumentServiceClient, IArchiveDocumentService>())
        {
            var archiveDocument = serviceClient.GetById(id);
            if (archiveDocument == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("ArchiveDocument not found.");

            Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Disposition");
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + archiveDocument.Document.Name);

            return File(archiveDocument.Document.DocumentData, "application/pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

To load the pdf-Document into an iframe, just call the function (still dummy-code -> hardcoded guid):

```
xtype: 'box',
width: 600,
height: 900,
autoEl: {
    tag: 'iframe',
    scrolling: 'no',
    seamless: 'seamless',
    frameborder: 0,
    src: 'Pdf/View/031d2151-5315-4574-aeb5-8154693a928d'
}
```

I hope, this solution will help other people.

Thanks to everybody who supported me!